# Equivalent Convex programs with different solutions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let $R_\kappa \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}_{sym}$, $S_\kappa \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}_{sym}$, $\eta_\kappa \in \mathbb{R}^+$, for a set $\{ \kappa \}$. Define a optimization problem $(1)$ as
\begin{align}
&\min_{\{S_\kappa\}} \sum_\kappa \eta_\kappa \exp( tr(R_\kappa S_\kappa) )\\
\text{s.t.}\quad& 2 (\sum_\kappa \exp(tr(S_\kappa)/2) - C) \leq 0\\
&\frac{1}{2}(\| S_\kappa \|^2_{Fr} -\alpha^2 ) \leq 0,\quad \forall \kappa
\end{align}
which is convex, and provided there is a feasible interior point has an optimal solution.

If I then have the function
$$ \phi(x) = \begin{cases} x^2,&x>0\\0,& x\leq 0 \end{cases}$$
and apply this to the second constraint I can get optimization problem $(2)$
\begin{align}
&\min_{\{S_\kappa\}} \sum_\kappa \eta_\kappa \exp( tr(R_\kappa S_\kappa) )\\
\text{s.t.}\quad& 2 (\sum_\kappa \exp(tr(S_\kappa)/2) - C) \leq 0\\
&\frac{1}{4}\phi(\| S_\kappa \|^2_{Fr} -\alpha^2)\leq 0,\quad \forall \kappa
\end{align}

$\phi$ is a convex function, and the feasible sets for both optimizations are the same, thus both $(1)$ and $(2)$ should have the same solution.

The first KKT condition for $(1)$ applied to the Lagrangian gives
\begin{align}
 0 &= \eta_\kappa R_\kappa \exp(tr(R_\kappa S_\kappa) ) + \lambda \mathcal{I} + \mu_\kappa S_\kappa
\end{align}
and applying the trace decomposition $A = a\mathcal{I} + \tilde{A}$ where $tr(\tilde{A}) = 0$ gives
\begin{align}
 0 &= \eta_\kappa \tilde{R}_\kappa \exp(tr(R_\kappa S_\kappa) ) + \mu_\kappa \tilde{S}_\kappa
\end{align}

The Lagrangian of $(2)$ is 
\begin{align}
\sum_\kappa \eta_\kappa \exp(tr(R_\kappa S_\kappa) + 2\lambda (\sum_\kappa \exp(tr(S_\kappa)/2) - C) + \sum_\kappa \frac{\mu_\kappa}{4}\phi(\| S_\kappa \|^2_{Fr} -\alpha^2)
\end{align}
differentiating w.r.t $S_\kappa$ and setting equal to $0$ gives
\begin{align}
0 &= \eta_\kappa R_\kappa \exp(tr(R_\kappa S_\kappa) ) + \lambda \mathcal{I} + \mu_\kappa S_\kappa \begin{cases}  (\| S_\kappa \|^2_{Fr} -\alpha^2), & \| S_\kappa \|^2_{Fr} -\alpha^2 > 0\\
0, & \| S_\kappa \|^2_{Fr} -\alpha^2 \leq 0
 \end{cases}
\end{align}
applying the trace decomposition gives
\begin{align}
0 &= \eta_\kappa \tilde{R}_\kappa \exp(tr(R_\kappa S_\kappa) ) + \mu_\kappa \tilde{S}_\kappa \begin{cases}  (\| S_\kappa \|^2_{Fr} -\alpha^2), & \| S_\kappa \|^2_{Fr} -\alpha^2 > 0\\
0, & \| S_\kappa \|^2_{Fr} -\alpha^2 \leq 0
 \end{cases}
\end{align}

which gives a contradiction: from primal feasibility we are on the $0$ branch, but we also know that $\tilde{R}_\kappa\neq 0$. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Taking the derivative of the trace gives the identity, $\frac{d tr(S_\kappa)}{d S_\kappa} = \mathcal{I}$, and taking the derivative of the exponential of trace comes from the chain rule.

Comment: You need some regularity conditions to apply KKT. For example, the second version of the second constraint can never be strictly feasible.

Comment: So then the second problem has the same primal solution, but does not have a dual solution?

Comment: I would have to think about that. The first problem has no duality gap because of Slater. I would need to do a little work to check if strong duality holds for the second problem.